# New variable using parts of string variable

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a variable in my dataset that looks like this:

```
IBM, Oracle, Ping
IBM, Ping
HP, IBM, Nagios
Solarwinds, HP, Nagios
BMC, Solarwinds, HP, IBM, Nagios, SCOM
```

I want to seperate each of these companies out and create new variables for each of these. For example, I want there to be a different variable for IBM, Nagiog, SCOM etc. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Not enough example material to work with. (It's not me that is downvoting all the questions with no working examples.)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I am brand new to R so still don't know enough to ask the right questions. I will keep this mind for the future! :)

Answer (score 0):

My reading of this question is that:

1. You have a column in a `data.frame` (say named "companies") that has a comma separated string of companies.
2. You want to split those values up, and create columns for each unique company.
3. I have no idea what you want to fill those columns with, so I assume that you want to create a binary or "presence" indicator of some sort.

If my reading is correct, try `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
cSplit_e(mydf, "companies", ",", type = "character", mode = "binary", fill = 0)
#                                companies companies_BMC companies_HP companies_IBM
# 1                      IBM, Oracle, Ping             0            0             1
# 2                              IBM, Ping             0            0             1
# 3                        HP, IBM, Nagios             0            1             1
# 4                 Solarwinds, HP, Nagios             0            1             0
# 5 BMC, Solarwinds, HP, IBM, Nagios, SCOM             1            1             1
# companies_Nagios companies_Oracle companies_Ping companies_SCOM companies_Solarwinds
# 1                0                1              1              0                    0
# 2                0                0              1              0                    0
# 3                1                0              0              0                    0
# 4                1                0              0              0                    1
# 5                1                0              0              1                    1
```

---

This assumes the data we are starting with is:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  companies = c("IBM, Oracle, Ping",
                "IBM, Ping",
                "HP, IBM, Nagios",
                "Solarwinds, HP, Nagios",
                "BMC, Solarwinds, HP, IBM, Nagios, SCOM"))
```

---

There's also a `drop` argument which can be set to `TRUE` if you want to remove the original column.